Windows 10 limits my file name to LESS than the standard 256
The entire filename in question is only 207 characters long. I just want to add a "1" to the front of it, and it will not allow me to type anything into it.
I have tried the following:

Edited the registry: set the LongPathsEnabled parameter of REG_DWORD
in the registry key HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ControlFileSystem
with a value 1. (this was actually already enabled)

Second, In the Local Group Policy Editor - in Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Filesystem, I have set the policy parameter named Enable Win32 long paths to Enabled.


Then I rebooted my computer.
Neither works. I could understand if I surpassed the 256 limit, but I have not. And a search on here turned up no other posts the same as this particular issue.
What could possibly be causing this? What can I do about it?

File Explorer doesn’t support LongPathsEnabled
